# How to format JSONArray with nested arrays

Tags: arrays, json, object, multidimensional-array, jsonexception

I wannt to access the fields in my JSONArray. The nested brackets inside the JSONArray is very troublesome. I can't see how this format is an acceptable JSONArray return value. I get an JSONException when I try to access a field (eg "rethink3__Address__c") using `getJSONObject()`.

```
 [
   [
      {
         "attributes":{
            "type":"rethink3__Listing__c",
            "url":"\/services\/data\/v42.0\/sobjects\/rethink3__Listing__c\/a06m0000005OPb9AAG"
         },
         "rethink3__Address__c":null,
         "Alarm_Code__c":null,
         "rethink3__Bathrooms__c":0,
         "rethink3__Bedrooms__c":0,
         "rethink3__Size__c":0,
         "Lock_Box_Code__c":null,
         "Lock_Box_Location_Notes__c":null,
         "_soupEntryId":1,
         "_soupLastModifiedDate":1537657104801
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "attributes":{
            "type":"rethink3__Listing__c",
            "url":"\/services\/data\/v42.0\/sobjects\/rethink3__Listing__c\/a06m0000005OPb9AAG"
         },
         "rethink3__Address__c":null,
         "Alarm_Code__c":null,
         "rethink3__Bathrooms__c":0,
         "rethink3__Bedrooms__c":0,
         "rethink3__Size__c":0,
         "Lock_Box_Code__c":null,
         "Lock_Box_Location_Notes__c":null,
         "_soupEntryId":1,
         "_soupLastModifiedDate":1537657104801
      }
   ]
]
```

Comment: `http://jsonviewer.stack.hu`, use this website to view how your JSON is structured.  it's very helpful for me at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `[]` = json array and `{}` = json object. So try this.

```
let myArray = [
    [
        {
            "attributes":{
                "type":"rethink3__Listing__c",
                "url":"\/services\/data\/v42.0\/sobjects\/rethink3__Listing__c\/a06m0000005OPb9AAG"
            },
            "rethink3__Address__c":null,
            "Alarm_Code__c":null,
            "rethink3__Bathrooms__c":0,
            "rethink3__Bedrooms__c":0,
            "rethink3__Size__c":0,
            "Lock_Box_Code__c":null,
            "Lock_Box_Location_Notes__c":null,
            "_soupEntryId":1,
            "_soupLastModifiedDate":1537657104801
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "attributes":{
                "type":"rethink3__Listing__c",
                "url":"\/services\/data\/v42.0\/sobjects\/rethink3__Listing__c\/a06m0000005OPb9AAG"
            },
            "rethink3__Address__c":null,
            "Alarm_Code__c":null,
            "rethink3__Bathrooms__c":0,
            "rethink3__Bedrooms__c":0,
            "rethink3__Size__c":0,
            "Lock_Box_Code__c":null,
            "Lock_Box_Location_Notes__c":null,
            "_soupEntryId":1,
            "_soupLastModifiedDate":1537657104801
        }
    ]
];

myArray.forEach((myNestedArray)=>{
    let obj = myNestedArray[0]
    console.log(obj.attributes.type);
    console.log(obj._soupLastModifiedDate);
})
```

Comment: Thanks this is the right idea. I accomplished same thing with java like below `for (int i=0;i<clean.length();i++){
    JSONArray y = clean.getJSONArray(i);
    x = y.getJSONObject(0);
    cleaner.put(x);
   }`